# How to save data frames in a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have some data frames which comes on different iterations of my code. Let it be some 100 iterations. Each time i write the data frame to `df` which i use to store the upcoming frame.

The data frames are

first iteration

```
       V1          V2           V3          V4  
      5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  
      4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  
      4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  
      4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  
      5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2
```

second iteration

```
          V1          V2           V3          V4  
          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  
          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  
          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  
          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  
          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2
```

third iteration

```
  V1          V2           V3          V4  
  5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  
  4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  
  4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  
  4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  
  5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2
```

and so on

Now at the end I want to have all the data frames in a list so I can process the list for other operation. How do I do this?

Here is a sample code

```
data = list.files(pattern=".csv")
data1 = lapply(data, function(x) read.csv(x, header = TRUE))
files = length(data1)
for(i in 1:length(files))
{
  ......
  code
  ......
}
 df   ## say some df is generated each time
```

Comment: Please include the code you used to generate these data.frames.

Comment: Something like: `lapply(1:100, function(u) {#do something returning a dataframe})`

Comment: And what do yo get after you execute the first two lines of your sample code?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel .. do you mean something like `data <- lapply(1:length(files), function(u) {df})`

Comment: Yes here you have la list of the same data.frame is `df` is defined somewhere.

Comment: @kdopen . i upload a list of files from my directory and process them . For each file i get a data frame say `df` , of which i want a list

Comment: See the posted answer, but your sample code seems to work and give you what you want. What is your specific problem with it? What goes wrong?

Comment: `lapply` takes a list and function as input, operate the function on each element of the list and returns a list. This is what you need there.

Comment: @kdopen Actually i don't have any problem in first three lines of code. I get a list in R from my working directory. so suppose i upload 100 files from my directory. I process each file and i get 100 new data frames ( each for a file) . Now i want to have a list of my new generated data frames. That is it!

Comment: But you *have* a list of your newly created data-frames. You used it to create the files you uploaded. I'm clearly missing something in your question.

Comment: Do you want to combine the data frames?  http://www.r-bloggers.com/concatenating-a-list-of-data-frames/

Comment: @kdopen I don't have a list yet. These file i uploaded are generated separately.

Comment: Then just append the new data frame to another list at the end of each iteration

Comment: @kdopen yes that is what i mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, I understand you are trying to generate a list of data.frame objects over sequential iterations of some algorithm - each of which produces a new data.frame.

Suppose we have some function `f()` which generates a new data.frame, from some source, and perhaps uploads the data.frame before returning it.

```
f <- function() {
    # read a file, do some work, produce a dataframe, etc
    df # return the new data.frame()
}
```

The problem with using `append` or something similar to add the new data.frame to the list is that is has a habit of "unrolling" the frame and merging it in.

Instead, your code needs a structure like this:

```
output_list <- list() # A list to hold the generated frames

while (more_work_to_do) {
    df <- f() #One iteration
    output_list[[length(output_list)+1]] <- df
}

# At this point, output_list is a list of the generated data frames
# with all their internal structure preserved.
```

It's important to use the `[[]]` operator for the insert to avoid the " number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length" error.  The `length(output_list)+1` construct simply means "one past the current end of the array" and in effect does an append for you without needing to maintain a separate counter.

Here's an example

```
> f<-function() { data.frame(x=rnorm(5), y=rnorm(5)) }
> output_list <- list()
> for (i in 1:5) output_list[[length(output_list)+1]] <- f()
> length(output_list)
[1] 5
> str(output_list)
List of 5
 $ :'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ x: num [1:5] -0.347 0.194 -0.406 -0.384 2.24
  ..$ y: num [1:5] -0.756 0.3417 -0.7542 0.1612 -0.0494
 $ :'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ x: num [1:5] 0.667 -0.186 0.602 -0.239 1.516
  ..$ y: num [1:5] 0.263 -1.322 0.604 -0.135 -0.339
 $ :'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ x: num [1:5] 1.064 -0.365 -1.584 0.163 0.142
  ..$ y: num [1:5] -0.0782 1.3314 0.0797 -0.4096 0.4819
 $ :'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ x: num [1:5] -2.0448 -0.4228 -0.5305 -0.0611 0.4114
  ..$ y: num [1:5] -0.608 -0.74 -0.196 -0.957 0.653
 $ :'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ x: num [1:5] 0.582 -1.029 -1.222 1.755 0.259
  ..$ y: num [1:5] 1.733 0.319 -0.597 -1.814 0.446
> output_list
[[1]]
           x           y
1 -0.3474823 -0.75595301
2  0.1941049  0.34170577
3 -0.4055180 -0.75424689
4 -0.3838479  0.16122522
5  2.2397387 -0.04936943

[[2]]
           x          y
1  0.6674517  0.2625242
2 -0.1859460 -1.3219586
3  0.6020241  0.6042548
4 -0.2387514 -0.1345904
5  1.5158875 -0.3392787

[[3]]
           x           y
1  1.0639814 -0.07823834
2 -0.3645768  1.33144410
3 -1.5839606  0.07973743
4  0.1630311 -0.40957609
5  0.1420562  0.48187377

[[4]]
            x          y
1 -2.04475082 -0.6083283
2 -0.42280601 -0.7396052
3 -0.53048188 -0.1961052
4 -0.06107144 -0.9571272
5  0.41136718  0.6526753

[[5]]
           x          y
1  0.5821866  1.7325293
2 -1.0289847  0.3186825
3 -1.2218606 -0.5971967
4  1.7548963 -1.8136810
5  0.2592219  0.4463977

>
```