# How to combine multiple data frames in a list in for loop in R?

Tags: r, list, for-loop, dataframe

I have a code similar to as shown below :

```
# initialize an empty list of dataframes here....
for (i in range 1:10) {
    # create a new data frame here....
    # append this newly created dataframe to the list here....
```

How can I create an empty list of dataframes at the start of the loop and then go on adding a newly created dataframe in each iteration of the for loop?

Comment: Not sure about what you want.  To create a list of empty data.frames, `replicate(5, data.frame())`

Comment: That is exactly what I did. But when I assign newly created dataframe to the list as `list_of_frames[i] <- newly_created_frame`, it's not working

Comment: Okay, so it worked as : `list_of_frames[[i]] <- newly_created_frame`. Not sure why though.

Comment: By using `[[`, you are getting the list element, but `[` will not get to that point.  Check `as.list(1:3)[[1]]` and `as.list(1:3)[1]`

Comment: "There are two other subsetting operators: [[ and $. [[ is similar to [, except it can only return a single value and it allows you to pull pieces out of a list. $ is a useful shorthand for [[ combined with character subsetting.

You need [[ when working with lists. This is because when [ is applied to a list it always returns a list: it never gives you the contents of the list. To get the contents, you need [[" [link](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save data frames in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29515571/how-to-save-data-frames-in-a-list)

Answer (score 2):

If the sole purpose is to merge the data frames, it may be easier to use the `merge_all` from the `reshape` package:

```
reshape::merge_all(your_list_with_dfs, ...)
```

Or alternatively, you may try:

```
do.call("rbind", your_list_with_dfs)
```

in order to append the rows.

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it was as follows (as suggested by @akrun)

```
list_of_frames <- replicate(10, data.frame())
for (i in range 1:10) {
    # create a new data frame called new_dataframe
    list_of_frames[[i]] <- new_dataframe
```

Comment: What is your end goal? There are better ways to create lists of data frames in R. Loop can be avoided.

Comment: End goal is something that requires running a Random Forest training function on training set with different input values.

Comment: Reframing - what data do you want to populate empty data frames in list with? Where is it coming from?

Answer (score -1):

```
myList <- vector(mode = "list", length = 10) # Create an empty list. 
                                             # Length depends on how many dataframe you want to append.

for (i in seq(1,10)) {

    myList[[i]] <- new_dataframe #append your new dataframe
}
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it was flagged for review.  Answers with no explanation are often considered low-quality. Please provide some commentary for why this is the correct answer.